# Windows Phone 7 swimming tiles effect

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, tiles

I wonder how to achieve effect of swiming tiles (like in windows phone 7, when you start arrange start menu tiles - other ones swim softly and randomly).
Someone have any ideas?

Comment: On any particular platform, hardware, or framework?

Comment: No, I think the problem is in good design random parameters stroryboard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out the HubTile implementation in the Windows Phone toolkit, full open source is up at http://silverlight.codeplex.com/ - it has a hub tile service that manages such communication.